# How to extract certain values from an array

Tags: php, slice

Example from here http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

```
$input = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
$output = array_slice($input, 2);      // returns "c", "d", and "e"
$output = array_slice($input, -2, 1);  // returns "d"
$output = array_slice($input, 0, 3);   // returns "a", "b", and "c"
```

But how to get for example "a", "d", and "e"?

like

```
$output = array_slice($input, 0, 1);
$output = array_slice($input, 3, 1);
$output = array_slice($input, -1, 1);
```

But in one variable. Is it possible?

Update. Want to use 1st, 3rd and last element of array. As if extract 1st, 3rd and last element and create new array only with the 3 elements.

Comment: What is the real task behind this question?

Comment: Any reason you want this "in one variable"?

Comment: Of course it's possible - you'd just write a custom function that effectively wrapped when the end of the array was encountered. (I'm presuming you'd be calling list like `array_slice_wrap($input, -2, 3)`.) Have you actually tried anything so far?

Comment: see the previous comments about "why down vote"

Comment: Must manage (process) only certain values (elements) from array.

Comment: And how do you define these "certain values"? Is there a common property to them or is it purely a matter of which index in the array it is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will have to throw [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/array_merge) into the mix, because [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/array_slice) can only extract a subsequence of an array, not an arbitrary number of elements spread over the entire array. Extract each subsequence separately and then merge them into one array:

```
$slice1 = array_slice($input, 0, 1);
$slice2 = array_slice($input, -2, 2);
$output = array_merge($slice1, $slice2);
```

Be aware however, that this will only work, if you really know each element in your array. In this case, you could just as well use direct array access, which will most likely generate less overhead and is much easier to read:

```
$output = array($input[0], $input[3], $input[4]);
```

It might be much more reasonable to use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter) or even a custom iterator. But you haven't provided enough information about your task to clearly say something about that.

**Edit:** 
If it's only a matter of notation, you could try specifying an array with all the relevant indexes, then switch it around using [`array_fill_keys()`](http://php.net/array_fill_keys) in order to use it with [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/array_intersect_key) to extract only the relevant elements from the array:

```
$indexes = array(0, 3, 4);
$indexArray = array_fill_keys($indexes, true);
$output = array_intersect_key($input, $indexArray);
```

Comment: $output = array($input[0], $input[3], $input[4]); This would be ok, if not many elements. But if, for example $output = array($input[0], $input[3], $input[4], $input[6], $input[7], $input[9], $input[10]); I just want to get shorter code.

Comment: If you can't specify which elements are relevant other than by index, you will eventually have to enumerate all indexes to do the extraction. It's only a matter of where and how to list them.

Comment: I added another way to write down what you want to do. You should wrap that in a function to clarify what it's doing, because it's not that obvious from the code. And I can't tell what impact it might have on the performance.